Set of random variables where each random variable is stochastically bounded. $O_p$ bound for max of set not necessarily the same?
Let $X = \{X_1, \dots, X_r \}$ be a set of random variables such that $X_i = O_p(a_n) \; \forall i$.
I would like to confirm that the statement I give below is correct.
It is not true in general that $\max{X} = O_p(a_n)$ ?
The converse is true though: $\max{X} = O_p(a_n) \, \implies X_i = O_p(a_n) \; \forall i$

If I start writing this out, we can see where the problem arises
$\mathbb{P}(\max{X} > a_n \delta) = \mathbb{P}(\exists \; i  \; \text{s.t} \quad X_i > a_n \delta)$
and therefore we would have to use union bound for example, and this would introduce the dimension of the set $X$ into the bound.

If we are in the deterministic case on the otherhand
with
$X = \{X_1, \dots, X_r \}$
a set of real deterministic sequences such that $X_i = O(a_n)$
By definition:
$\exists M_i, N_i \quad$ s.t $\quad X_i \leq M_i a_n \quad \forall n > N_i$
Let $M = \{M_1, \dots M_r\} $ and $N = \{N_1, \dots N_r\} $
Then we can just say $\max{X} < \max\{M\} a_n$ $\forall n > \max\{N\}$.
And hence $(\max{X}) = O(a_n)$
